# Emacs: Mode doesn't load on startup

Tags: emacs, ide, lisp, elisp, dot-emacs

I'm using Emacs under Win64. I want to load a mode called `gas-mode.el` on startup.

**What I wrote:**

```
C-x C-f c:/Program Files (x86)/emacs-23.1/.emacs

(autoload 'gas-mode "c:/Program Files (x86)/emacs-23.1/lips/gas-mode.el")
(setq auto-mode-alist 
     (append '(("\\.asm\\'" . gas-mode) ("\\.inc\\'" . gas-mode))
             auto-mode-alist))

C-x C-s
C-x C-c

<Restarting...>

M-x gas-mode
```

**Emacs' answer:**

I never got a response different to:

```
[No match]
```

**My Question:**

How can I get Emacs to autoload `gas-mode.el` on startup? Any idea? Thanks.

**Where my `.emacs` user init file's located:**

Emacs tells me that I can find it in my the emacs folder of my program directory:

```
user-init-file

C-j

"c:/Program Files (x86)/emacs-23.1/.emacs"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know too much about lisp or emacs lisp but you can go to the .emacs file where ever it is located. Then in that file add this code

```
(load "c:/Program Files (x86)/emacs-23.1/lips/gas-mode.el")
```

Also in your load path you have "lips" and i believe it should be "lisp" so that might be one of the issues.

One more thing, you don't have to restart emacs every time you can go to the last parenthesis and do `C-x C-e` which will evaluate the form. To evaluate the bugger you would do M-X load-file /.emacs

Comment: Thanks for the `C-x C-e` tip. But neither restarting nor `C-x C-e`  does the right thing with the `autoload` code from my question.  Now I will try your code - maybe your code (using `load` instead of `autoload`) will work correctly. But in every manual they use `autoload` (not `load`) - why?

Comment: Ok, after looking at it "load" loads the .el file on startup and "autoload" will load the .el file on the first use of it. Other than that i am not sure sorry :|

Comment: Thanks. One more question: We write `(autoload 'gas-mode "path")`, but we don't write `(load 'gas-mode "path")` (instead of `(load "path")` without `'gas-mode`), why?

Comment: I removed the hall Emacs and installed it again. Now it's working. I don't know why and I think it's better to not know it. ;-)